# WCF restful web service for SharePoint (WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)

Tags: c#, json, wcf, sharepoint

I've a block of code

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "/projectSites")]
    IEnumerable<Web> GetProjectSites();
}
```

And the problem is that when I use

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
```

I get good responce..
But when using

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```

I get an error

> The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

What can wrong with it? I need exactly Bare style, as I ned to get responce of

```
{[{"description":"","id":"bb9effb4-27a8-4ad1-9513-5bccaa2eccfd","name":"s1","url":"http:smth"}]}
```

but not

```
{"GetProjectSitesResult":[{"description":"","id":"bb9effb4-27a8-4ad1-9513-5bccaa2eccfd","name":"s1","url":"http:smth"}]}
```